# is there any function in Magento to get Parent ID (Grouped) with an array of children ids as input?

Tags: magento

Consider the below situation (assume all the products retrieved belongs to a grouped product)

```
$collection= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
$productIds = $collection->getAllIds();
```

is there any function in Magento to fetch all the parent ids of children ids in above array "$productIds"?

```
ex : getAllGroupedParentIDs($productIds)
```

Thanks,

Balan

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve an array of Grouped Product IDs for each simple product ID with something like this:

```
$parentIdArray = array();
foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
    $parentIdArray[$productId] = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped')->getParentIdsByChild($productId);
};
```